# Building Unity game for Android 8.0

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am done with my Unity game project and building it for android platforms. The minimum API level is 4.1 and highest API installed in my SDK root folder is 27. However version of SDK tools is 25.2.5. I can run the game on my own phone which has android version 5.0 installed however my friend's phone which has 8.0 can not run it. I am quite confused about it since i already have API 27 installed on my computer for building process and version 8.0 should have no problem with running my game. And also on another phone which has 4.4.2 can not run it although the minimum version is 4.1. I am attaching the build settings from Unity as a picture below. Would you please help me troubleshoot? Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the problem is related to device filter.... you are generating only for x86 and armv7 architectures, you are excluding 64bit architectures

Comment: Oh yeah I see your point. But i don't know how i can handle that because there are only 3 options (x86, armv7 and both combined). Would you please recommend me a solution?

Comment: Well, i read some previous posts and discussions on this problem and apparently unity does not support building for 64 bit platforms. So does it literally mean that my game will not be available for more than 50 percent of Google Play Store?